# fail install hhvm with homebrew

Tags: homebrew, hhvm

i try to install hhvm via

```
brew install hhvm
```

i got this error :

```
Sinas-MacBook-Pro:~ sinamiandashti$ brew install hhvm
==> Downloading https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/archive/HHVM-3.2.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/hhvm-3.2.0.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file hphp/runtime/ext/gd/libgd/gdft.cpp
Hunk #1 FAILED at 63.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file hphp/runtime/ext/gd/libgd/gdft.cpp.rej
```

Comment: The maintainer of the hhvm formula would probably appreciate it if you raised this issue with them: https://github.com/mcuadros/homebrew-hhvm/issues

Comment: @TimSmith already did that ... no response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the formula is fixed

plz use

```
brew install hhvm --HEAD
```